# Android Studio is not using gradle to build my projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I imported a project from Eclipse and android studio is not using my gradle scripts to build the project. Anyone else having this issue? Is there anyway to force Android Studio to use gradle to build my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you import an existing project with no gradle configuration, Android Studio will use the old build system. If you want to use gradle, you should follow the instructions in the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: thanks... I followed those instructions but obviously I missed a step somewhere... The wrapper option was grayed out so I set the Gradle home path and used the second option.

Answer (score 3):

Delete .idea and .iml, then open your project again